# Opengl - Why glTranslatef comes first while coding and glutwiresphere next

Tags: c++, opengl

Before I begin I would like to thank stackoverflow community members for the super fast and exact answer.

I saw an example and am attaching the excerpt from the code here

```
   glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef (0.0, 0.0, -5.0);


/*    clip lower half -- y < 0          
   glClipPlane (GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqn);
   glEnable (GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
/*    clip left half -- x < 0           
   glClipPlane (GL_CLIP_PLANE1, eqn2);
   glEnable (GL_CLIP_PLANE1);
   */

   glRotatef (90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glutWireSphere(1.5, 20, 15);
   glPopMatrix();
   glFlush ();
```

My doubt what we are 'translating' and 'rotating' before the wiresphere is actually formed.
To be precise why `glRotate()` and `glTranslate()` come before `glutWireSphere` ?

Comment: Why still using deprecated API dude?It takes you nowhere.Start learning modern OpenGL

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is not a scene graph. There no such thing as "objects" in it. There's nothing that could be "formed". All OpenGL knows is points, lines and triangled, drawn to a pixel framebuffer canvas. *(why don't I have a template with that prologue stored, I write it about every 2nd OpenGL answer.)*

One you've drawn something with OpenGL that's it. OpenGL will not remember it. So what OpenGL does is, it puts the coordinates of the points, lines or triangles drawn through the transformation steps and the resulting numbers tell, where to draw on the screen. Obviously the transformation must be set, before drawing then.

Answer (score 1):

What `glTranslate()` and `glRotate()` do is multiply the current matrix with a particular transformation matrix (a translation or rotation one, respectively). `glutWireSphere()` specifies the sphere in the currently active modelview coordinates.

In other words, you first set up the modelview matrix so that it represents the local coordinate system you want for the sphere, and then create the sphere in it.

Comment: Actually I am beginner in opengl glModelview is used to do transform or scale or ... to the model rt?

Comment: @SiddharthTaunk If you're a beginner, I suggest you find and follow a good tutorial or (even better) a graphics book. That should explain all you need to know. But in short: the modelview matrix is used to transform from object space to world space (the *model* part) and then from world space to camera (=view) space (the *view* part).

Comment: Hi. I am reading the Opengl redbook. are there any other good books for beginners in your view?

Comment: @SiddharthTaunk Redbook is the canonical resource, of course. One of the first chapters there (ch.3 in 4th edition) describes the model-view-projection system, matrix operations etc. As an alternative, I know some people prefer the OpenGL Superbible. As far as books go, I can't help much further - I studied CG at university, so I was just following courses (graphics itself, as well as linear algebra).

Comment: @SiddharthTaunk: Actually you don't "create" a sphere, or any other kind of object for that matter, in OpenGL. See my answer.